# KendoUI Command with template Issue with KendoUI Grid

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendoUI web and new to it. I've got a problem in the following code.

```
columns:[
{
    command:"edit",
    template:"&lt;a href ='index_code.html' &gt; #=edit# &lt;/a&gt;",
    width: "80px",
},
{
    field: 'edit',
    template: '&lt;a href="index_code.html"&gt; #=edit# &lt;/a&gt'
}]
```

when i click on field edit column, it diverts the page to index_code.html.

but this is not happening on command edit column, it performs no action.

How to make the command button active??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but:

1. when using `command` you cannot use `template`.
2. when defining a `command` you are expected that every `button` should have the same text.

But if you want it to looks like a button despite it is a link, that is -of course- possible using `template`.

Example:

```
columns   : [
    {
        field: 'edit',
        template: '<a href="index_code.html" class="k-button k-button-icontext"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span>#= City #</a>',
        width: 100
    } 
]
```

JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/626qB/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
columns:[
{
     command:  "edit",
     width : 100
},
{
     field: 'edit',
     template: '<a href="index_code.html" class="k-button k-button-icontext"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span>#= City #</a>',
     width: 100
}]
```

**Script**

```
$('.k-grid-edit').on("click", function () {
    alert('hi');
});
```

see demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/626qB/4/